# MySQL word boundaries with parenthesis inside the two words

Tags: mysql

I can match the word **Burger** in this `REGEXP` word boundary `[[:<:]]Burger[[:>:]]`. However, I have another entry which is **Burger (Cheese)** and cannot be seen by the word boundary `[[:<:]]Burger (Cheese)[[:>:]]`. What am I have to do to allow two words and parenthesis on the word boundary?

Comment: I don't know what your funny smileys are for next to the words but it seems to work for me... http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fQN

Comment: You don't show any code but parenthesis have a special meaning in regular expressions so yes you have to escape them in order to search for a literal one.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - that is the code exactly just add `REGEXP` as I use it on MySQL.

Comment: Question is tagged as PHP. Since you cannot inject raw SQL in PHP (other languages offer such feature, not PHP) I was assuming you were using a PHP string (where backslash is also a escape character). (If PHP is not involved at all you should remove the tag.) In any case, if you are sure your code is correct thus doesn't need to be shared, what is your question exactly?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, `WHERE ... REGEXP '[[:<:]]Burger (Cheese)[[:>:]]'` does not match `Burger (Cheese)`.

The first issue is that you aren't even looking for parenthesis. `(` and `)` have a special meaning in regular expressions, they are used to define groups, thus need to be escaped. However, the escape char in regexp (backslash) is the same as in strings—since your regexp is inside a string you need to escape the backslash as well: `\\(`.

However, `WHERE ... REGEXP '[[:<:]]Burger \\(Cheese\\)[[:>:]]'` won't match either, what takes us to the second issue. `[[:>:]` matches a word boundary but [parenthesis is not a word character](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#sa74869348):

> A word character is an alphanumeric character in the `alnum` class or an underscore (`_`).

You no longer have a `[[:>:]` word boundary at the of the `(Cheese)` string because the word ends with last `e`.

You'll have to rethink your logic. If it suites your specs, you can add the closing parenthesis to the end of the expression, e.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM (
    ->  SELECT 'Burger' AS foo
    ->  UNION ALL SELECT 'Burger (Cheese)'
    ->  UNION ALL SELECT 'Yet Another Burger'
    ->  UNION ALL SELECT 'Burger Extras'
    ->  UNION ALL SELECT 'Coffee'
    -> ) x
    -> WHERE foo REGEXP '[[:<:]]Burger \\(Cheese([[:>:]]|\\))';
+-----------------+
| foo             |
+-----------------+
| Burger (Cheese) |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```